# Firebase offline mode

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I´m looking to implement something like an offline mode, so my app still works when going somewhere where there is no connection or when you dont want to use mobile data. In my database each user has a node with data related to this user. This is the data I want to store locally.

Now I´m wondering how to do this. My first Idea was to set `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` and download the data of a user when the offline mode is being activated but that doesn´t seem to be a very good solution.

Are there any other proper ways to implement this feature?

Comment: Why do you want to keep user information on user's device? What's the point of login system if you want offline mode?

Comment: My app is a fitness app, you can create an account and then create your own workout routines. Imagine you would go somewhere to workout where there is no connection, then you couldn´t access your workout routine meaning you couldn´t workout...

Comment: Why doesn't your approach seem like a very good solution to you?

Answer (score 0):

Heard that firebase wont be able to keep offline data for more than 3 days, Dont know whether its rectified already or not